# How SAS handles missing values while fitting linear regression model

Tags: regression, missing-data, sas

While fitting a linear regression model in SAS, if the dataset has missing values (either missing y, or missing x or both), will SAS just ignore the records that have at least one missing value(y,x)? Or will it try to do some form of imputation?

Comment: I would be extremely surprised if **any** statistical package would do imputation without you asking for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS completely excludes observations with missing values - [SAS Reference -](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_reg_sect026.htm)